# How does publish/subscribe work with the Neo4j Reactivity driver for Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, neo4j, reactive-programming, master-slave

I am working on a Meteor app where you can create Neo4j "Room" nodes and "DOOR" relationships. Each room should have only one door leading to any other given room.

I'm using Dmitriy Aristarkhovich's [Neo4j Reactivity](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/ostrio-Neo4jreactivity) driver.

I want to create a real-time master-slave system where a choice made by the user affects what other choices are possible.

To illustrate this, in the Neo4j browser on port 7474, I create a simple network of rooms, like this:

```
CREATE
(a:Room {name: "Room 1"})
-[:DOOR]->
(b:Room {name: "Room 2"}),
a-[:DOOR]->
(c:Room {name: "Room 3"}),
b-[:DOOR]->a
RETURN a, b, c
```

[image: Rooms and doors]

In this schema:

- Room 1 already has all the outgoing doors that it can have
- Room 2 can be linked to Room 3 by a door
- Room 3 can be linked to both Room 1 and Room 2

I want to show two drop-down menus:

- a master menu to choose a starting room for a door
- a slave menu to choose from the possible ending rooms, given the starting room.

Here's the Meteor-flavour HTML that I use to create these menus:

```
<body>
  {{> addDoor}}
</body>

<template name="addDoor">
  <p>Add a Door from
    <select id="fromRoomName">
      {{#each fromRooms}}
        {{> fromRoom}}
      {{/each}}
    </select>

    to: 
    <select id="toRoomName">
      {{#each toRooms}}
        {{> toRoom}}
      {{/each}}
    </select>
  </p>
</template>

<template name="fromRoom">
  <option value="{{name}}">{{name}}</option>
</template>

<template name="toRoom">
  <option value="{{name}}">{{name}}</option>
</template>
```

This is what these menus should look like when Room 3 is selected in the master menu.

[image: Master-slave menus]

Here is the JavaScript that I am using:

```
var queries = {
  "roomsForNewDoors": {
    collection: Meteor.neo4j.collection("RoomsForNewDoors")
  , query: 
     "MATCH (entrance:Room), (exit:Room) " +
     "WHERE NOT (entrance)-[:DOOR]->(exit) " +
     "AND entrance <> exit " +
     "RETURN entrance"
  , link: "entrance"
  }
, "newDoorsForRoom": {
    collection: Meteor.neo4j.collection("NewDoorsForRoom")
  , query: 
      "MATCH (entrance:Room), (exit:Room) " +
      "WHERE entrance.name = '{name}' " +
      "AND NOT (entrance)-[:DOOR]->(exit) " +
      "AND entrance <> exit " +
      "RETURN exit"
  , options: {name: "Room 2"}
  , link: "exit"
  }
}


if (Meteor.isServer) {
  ;(function (){
    var queryKeys = Object.keys(queries)
    queryKeys.forEach(publish)

    function publish(key) {
      var queryData = queries[key]
      var query = queryData.query
      var collection = queryData.collection

      collection.publish(key, publishCallback)

      function publishCallback(){
        return query
      }
    }
  })()
}


if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Tracker.autorun(function createSubscriptions(){
    var queryKeys = Object.keys(queries)
    queryKeys.forEach(subscribe)

    function subscribe(key) { //, index, array){
      var queryData = queries[key]
      var options = queryData.options
      var link = queryData.link
      var collection = queryData.collection
      var subscription = collection.subscribe(key, options, link)
    }
  })

  function getResults(queryData) {
    var collection = queryData.collection
    var cursor = collection.find()
    return cursor
  }

  Template.addDoor.events({
    'change #fromRoomName': function () {
      var fromRoomId = $("#fromRoomName :selected").text()
      Session.set("fromRoomId", fromRoomId)
    }
  })

  Template.addDoor.helpers({
    fromRooms: function() {
      var results = getResults(queries.roomsForNewDoors)
      return results
    }

  , toRooms: function () {
      var key = "newDoorsForRoom"
      var queryData = queries[key]
      var options = { name: Session.get("fromRoomId") }
      var link = queryData.link
      var collection = queryData.collection
      collection.subscribe(key, options, link)

      var results = getResults(queryData)
      return results
    }
  })
}
```

When I test the two `MATCH` queries in the Neo4j browser (using "Room 2", for example, instead of `'{name}'`, I get exactly the results I expect. Using the Neo4j Reactivity driver, the first `MATCH` query runs fine, but the second query produces an empty set of results.

I suspect that there is something fundamental about the publish/subscribe process that I have not understood. I would be grateful for any help in getting this functionality to work.

Full project is available here:

```
git clone git@github.com:blackslate/Neo4j-issues.git
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might not be a publish/subscribe issue. Try removing the quotes surrounding the `{name}` parameter.

That is, change:

```
"WHERE entrance.name = '{name}' "
```

to:

```
"WHERE entrance.name = {name} ".
```